# How to update GTFS static data stored locally

Tags: static, updates, gtfs

How should the regular updates to the GTFS static data provided by the Agencies through their text files be handled?

Should all this static data be deleted from the data stores and then completely reloaded from the Agency's new GTFS text files ?
T
his method would be used if the identifiers of say Route_id, Trip_id or stop_id can be reassigned between updates.

For example the new GTFS data files show that Stop_id "x" which was assigned to Trip "Y" is now assigned to Trip "Z".

If these entity identifiers are never reassigned then the new GTFS files need to be compared to the local data and based on the results; records need to be removed, updated or added to each table.

Erick.

Answer (score 0):

The only safe way is to load the new feed completely and then switch over to it on successful completion. While GTFS best practices at

https://gtfs.org/best-practices/#dataset-publishing--general-practices

do recommend that providers maintain persistent identifiers for stop_id, route_id and agency_id where possible, it is not a requirement of the specification and in practice they do often (particularly stop_id's) change in feeds.

Comment: Thank you for that. I did look for such a standard but never found it.
 As I have my own custom tables which reference the route and stops I may need to run some sort of validation check first. To check if no reassignment have occurred.

 Reloading all GTFS data takes  less than a minute so user disruption is minimal.

Erick